# Sound laggy and distorted

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, 64-bit, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell 1764 laptop (Windows 7 64 bit), and I'm having an issue with the sound. It's been happening for a while, possibly since I re-installed windows a while back.

The sound sometimes will have a crackling, laggy, distorted sound. However, it plays fine sometimes. It will constantly play the windows logon sound distorted and laggy when I logon to the computer.

I assume this is a driver issue so I downloaded DPC Latency Checker, and sure enough, there some bad signs. I started disabling devices in device manager and it got better when I disabled the following items:

- Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller - 3B30
- Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 - 3B42
- Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 - 3B44
- Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 - 3B4C

After disabling those devices, the DPC Latency Checker leveled out and the sound at windows logon sounded normal every time. I looked for an update for these devices but was unsuccessful in finding a driver.

Here's the version info on those devices:

- Driver Provider: Microsoft
- Driver Date: 6/21/2006
- Driver Version: 6.1.7601.17514

Anyone out there know a fix to this or where I can find updated drivers? If you need more info, please let me know and I will get it for you.

Thanks!

Comment: Did disabling these devices give you any bad results, such as things missing? If not, why bother? The SMBus, however, should be needed for getting device temperature values...

Comment: When I disabled these devices, the wireless adapter is unavailable.

Comment: I see. Try my solution then, hope it works!

Answer (score 2):

How about trying Intel's own driver detection and installation routine [here](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect?iid=dc_iduu)?

Also, if that doesn't work for you, try downloading and installing the [Intel Chipset Driver Software](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=20775&lang=eng) directly. That (normally) outfits every Intel related device with a Intel driver so you can be sure to have the best and newest ones installed.

I always install the chipset software, especially because it increases the computer's speed and stability. The Windows standard drivers work, but they're not optimal! I'm thankful for them because they offset the time for me to get proper drivers installed.